# Retrieve a variable from a function that crashed matlab

Tags: matlab, variables

Is there a way to retrieve the output of a function that did not complete properly?

For instance, a (non global) variable that was correctly computed by a function but that couldn't be saved properly because of syntax errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In principle, you can't look into a function once the program has stopped with an error. (That's why I often try to avoid functions.)

However, you can achieve what you want by entering **debugging mode**, using the [`dbstop`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) function to set a breakpoint:

> The `dbstop` function is used to temporarily stop the execution of a
>       program and give the user an opportunity to **examine the local
>       workspace**.

In particular, typing

```
dbstop if error
```

in the command window before running your code will make it stop at the point that caused the error and look at the variables within that function.

To **restore normal behaviour** you need the [`dbclear`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbclear.html) function. Type

```
dbclear if error
```

to remove the previously set breakpoint, or

```
dbclear all
```

to remove all breakpoints.

Comment: I will definitely use this from now on. It's very frustrating to run a code for 8 days and realize once it crashed that the output must be somewhere in the memory, just nowhere to be found.

Comment: I know what you mean... Functions hide all their internal data. That's often good, but sometimes frustrating. I'd rather have everything in sight.